# VueJS not render data on DOM inside electron application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I have an electron project where I'm implementing vuejs inside it. I'm able to load vue script and the browser window will open correctly the index.html file that contains the GUI that is made using bootstrap 4. I've noticed that the vue instance will not process the syntax `{{ hello }}` that is used by vue. I don't know where the problem is, but I think it's something related with the electron way of work that will cause problems to vue ?

I've installed it using the `npm install vue --save-dev` and all the project dependencies like bootstrap and jQuery was installed with the same method.

here is my code

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "clients-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple hosting credentials manager app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "dexie": "^2.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

main.js Javascript

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

function createWindow(){
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  win.loadFile('index.html');

  var myapp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      hello: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  });
  console.log(myapp);
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-4" id="app">
  <ul class="nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ hello }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't define `hello` ,  you defined `message`  in VUE Data

use this

`var myapp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      hello: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  });`

Comment: In the question there is a mistake with the code, I've pasted the worng vue part.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project using electron-vue boilerplate.

You can simply try it with npm.

```
# Install vue-cli and scaffold boilerplate
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue my-project

# Install dependencies and run your app
cd my-project
yarn # or npm install
yarn run dev # or npm run dev
```

For more information, please refer to the link https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/content/en/.